# Multi-repos pull request in TFS

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, pull-request

**Context**

- Our source management is under Git / TFS
- 2 developers work in 2 different repositories
- dev1 provides interfaces for dev2
- both must be tested in a common context, the pull request can be approved only if both are working together
- to make them working together, both repos are agregated
  into Dev:

  - \Dev\repo1
  - \Dev\repo2

**Question**: 
How to create a single pull request in TFS that allows to build and validate both repositories ?

Answer (score 0):

No, we cannot create pull request between repositories.

Curretnly TFS only supports pull requests from different branches within the same repository. There is a [User Voice here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/7159890-support-pull-requests-from-different-repositories) to request that feature, you can go and vote it up to achieve it in future.

So, you can try to create two branches instead of two repositories. Then 2 developers work in 2 different branches.

---

**Separately talk about building with multiple repositories**, you can try following below steps to do that:

1. Navigate to Repo1
2. Create a **submodule** reference from Repo1 to Repo2 with the
   command `git submodule add`.

> git submodule add
>   https://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/{team-project-name}/_git/repo2

3. Then check “**Checkout submodules**” option in your build
   definition.

See [Multiple Git Repositories with Submodules](https://www.benday.com/2016/11/04/one-tfs-build-multiple-git-repositories-with-submodules/) for details.

[image]

Comment: @elike Have you resolved your issue by above workaround? any update for this?

Comment: Thanks Andy for this answer.  
We cannot use different branches instead of different repositories as they are too big and must be split.  

Submodules are a rather static structure whereas the repositories that will need be in sync in a single pull request will change all the time.  
---
I want to 
Add an option to pull request: In sync with another repo ? 
- Empty = no
- Filled with other repo and source branch otherwise

Comment: @elike Unfortunately it's not supported for now. Just as I mentioned in above answer, you can vote up the [User Voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/7159890-support-pull-requests-from-different-repositories) to achieve the feature in future.

Comment: Here is the workaround I'll try to implement:<br>
1. developer_1 makes a commit with a message "compo_1===>compo_2 followed by description"
2. Compo_1 build analyses the changeset's commit messages
and creates a file with 
compo_2 requires_build_of compo_1


2.1. Identify the list of commits to be merged
Try:$ git log int_branch..feature
2.2. Check all the commit messages between the latest merge to integration and the latest commit on the feature branch
3. PR2 triggers a build which looks at this file common to all builds and triggers compo_1 build

Answer (score 0):

## here is my *workaround*

Since Options cannot be given in the Create pull request dialog, I ask the developer to pass this information in his commits’ messages.

1. Get the list of commits brought by the PR
2. For each commit,
   analyse its message -> get the delivery options
3. For each commit,
   get its changeset (list of pathnames) -> list of components to build
4. Store the options for next build step

The developer has to take care at commit time, it is less convenient but it works